# Azure Group Variables not picking my appsetting.json file variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I am working on Azure DevOps, and using Azure CD pipelines to deploy my web app into the Azure webapp service, I am using Azure group variables to Substituting my appsetting values to my defined values mentioned in group variable.

**Below is my appsetting.json file**

> "**ConnectionStrings**": {
>       "**AllegationDBConnectionString**": "Server=sqlserver;Database=database;User ID=username; pwd
>   =password;"   },

My group variables are [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwtr.png).

I have tried adding:

1. AllegationDBConnectionString
2. ConnectionStrings:AllegationDBConnectionString
3. ConnectionStrings

in **Name** section of group variable but not working.
How I can substitute value of AllegationDBConnectionString in Azure group variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if `ConnectionStrings` is the top level element of your json - your variable name has to be:

```
ConnectionStrings.AllegationDBConnectionString
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#json-variable-substitution-example